# Зависание phpMyAdmin после изменения пароля

Tags: mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Доброе время суток форумчане.
Создал БД, создал таблицу "*user*" провел над ней скрипты.
Решил поменять пароли[введите сюда описание ссылки](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zpsbhdwbtqv7m9n/user_root_localhost.png?dl=0):
зашел на вкладку «*Privileges*», там один пользователь с разными «Host». В пользователе где host = 127.0.0.1 – я пароль изменил (*Edit privileges -> Change password*) на свой.
После изменения пароля у пользователя с host = localhost, Выпадает сообщение «*The password for “root”@”localhost” was changed successfully*», далее при выборе этой же БД, появляется сообщение «loading» и программа **ЗАВИСАЕТ**.
Если не дожидаться пропадания сообщения и обновить phpMyAdmin, то он не загружается и выкидывает ошибку:

```
«MySQL said: Documentation
Cannot connect: invalid settings. 
Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the
connection. You should check the host, username and password in your
configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by   
the administrator of the MySQL server.»
```

Перегрузка MySQL - не помогает
Что я делаю не так?

открыл файл "*...\home\localhost\www\Tools\phpmyadmin\config.inc.php*"
сделал замены ['password'] и ['AllowNoPassword']:

```
CollapsedWrap disabledLine numbers off
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root'; // MySQL user
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '58fvcjm3ew0fvke8iudcuj'; // MySQL password (only needed
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```

запустил MySQL (Endels), ошибка (phpMyAdmin):

```
"MySQL said: Documentation
Cannot connect: invalid settings. 
phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the      
connection. You should check the host, username and password in your    
configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by
the administrator of the MySQL server."
```

Comment: Строка cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] закомментирована? Если нет, то что в ней прописано? Пробовали перезагрузить сервер MySQL?

Comment: Строка не закоментирована: **/* User for advanced features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';**. У меня стоит Endels, который я перезагружаю, который я перезагружаю каждый раз после изменения параметров.

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что controluser используется для управления базой данных для обслуживания phpMyAdmin. Он в принципе может работать без этой базы данных. Более того, если вы поменяли тип входа на config, то можете задействовать для управления базой данных phpMyAdmin пользователя по умолчанию. Лучше всего будет закомментировать следующие строки config.inc.php

```
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlhost'] = '';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlport'] = '';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = 'pmapass';
```

Comment: Строк     *// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlhost'] = '';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlport'] = '';
* в файле не было, остальные  *// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'root';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';
*закоментировал. Но проблема (в первом сообщении) **осталась**.